# Cannot create shared link with Dropbox API for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

This used to work before I updated to Swift 3, but I don't think this is really coming from this. Here is my problem:

I would like to create a Dropbox sharable link from my Swift app as follow:

```
client.sharing.createSharedLinkWithSettings(path: myPath).response { response, error in
   if let link = response {
      // share the link
   } else {
      print(error)
   }
}
```

but this is the error I get:

```
[request-id 431f08cc7e243504a437cec661247dd2] API route error - {
   ".tag" = "email_not_verified";
}
```

and I don't really understand how should I verify the email.
I can log in with dropbox, I authorised the app, I can write files and folders, etc.

Comment: Did Dropbox send you a verification email?

Comment: @sdasdadas thank you. I didn't received any email because the configured server was a POP one I haven't access to. I tried with another account and I got the verification email!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't received a verification email on my device. I tried with a different account and received this verification email from dropbox.